# How to make padding to not affect width, height and size

Tags: html, css

I want to padding work like absolute positioning. So It wont hurt other things.

I'm using `Hover.css` by **IanLunn**. I want the line animation to be under the List item.
Because of that I'm using padding to position the hover animation:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sovth.jpg

In the image, line animation apears too close to text. I want it to be little far from that without hurting other elements.
I can move it with padding but it does hurt other elements and box-sizing:border-box !important; does not change anything.

```css
.navbarUlDiv {
  margin-top:35px;

  }

.navbarUl {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 0;
}

.navbarLi {
  padding: 4px 5px 4px 5px !important;
  margin: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
  display: inline;
  color: #595959;
  font-size: 16px;
  transition: 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.navbarLi a{
  padding-bottom: 80px;

  }
```

```html
<div class="navbarUlDiv">
    <ul class="navbarUl text-center">

        <li class="navbarLi"><a href="#" class="hvr-underline-from-right">1</a></li>
        <li class="navbarLi"><a href="#" class="hvr-underline-from-right">2</a></li>
        <li class="navbarLi"><a href="#" class="hvr-underline-from-right">3</a></li>
        <li class="navbarLi"><a href="#" class="hvr-underline-from-right">4</a></li>

    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: please specify u r requirement clearly add some more details ? if it possible add u r expected op img.

Comment: Please explain what you're trying to achieve (and why it doesn't work so far) more clearly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If i am right u can try this

```css
.navbarUlDiv {
  margin-top:35px;
}

.navbarUl {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 0;
}

.navbarLi {
  padding: 4px 5px 4px 5px !important;
  margin: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
  display: inline;
  color: #595959;
  font-size: 16px;
  transition: 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.navbarLi a{
  box-sizing:border-box !important;
  padding-bottom:0;
  position:relative
}
.navbarLi a:after{
background:red;
content:"";
position:absolute;
left:0px;
right:0px;
width:0;
height:3px;
bottom:-10px;
transition: all ease 0.3s;
opacity:0;
margin:auto;
}
.navbarLi a:hover:after{
width:100%;
opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbarUlDiv">
    <ul class="navbarUl text-center">

        <li class="navbarLi"><a href="#" class="hvr-underline-from-right">1</a></li>
        <li class="navbarLi"><a href="#" class="hvr-underline-from-right">2</a></li>
        <li class="navbarLi"><a href="#" class="hvr-underline-from-right">3</a></li>
        <li class="navbarLi"><a href="#" class="hvr-underline-from-right">4</a></li>

    </ul>
</div>
```